# should my left shifter be clicking more than twice

Tags: shifter

So the left shifter is for my front mech. When I twist it, it can click  mor than twice. I have three chain rings at the front. Is this normal? Right now when u turn it try changing gears the mech doesn't line up with the indicated chain ring

Answer (score 1):

The lining up (or not) suggests some tuning is in order, but it is normal to have multiple clicks per shift on many models, to allow fine tuning of the shift while riding (if you count the clicks carefully you may find that the middle chainring is at a different position when approached from the larger compared to the smaller chainring). When you say twist, are you talking about something like revoshift?

[image: revoshift shifter]

The revoshift I'm familiar with certainly does this.

The adjustment of the font mech for not lining up is more likely to be a matter of limit screws than cable tension -- see [Sheldon Brown (skip to the limit screws)](http://sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html#front) among many HowTos for this.

Comment: Yes, multiple clicks on the front shifter is pretty common, for triple fronts.  My "brifter" does this.  It allows you to "fine tune" the chain position, as stated.  But even without fine tuning the chain should be fairly well centered over the center ring when that one is selected -- perhaps just rubbing a little.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, that sounds similar to what I've seen. The revoshift isn't my bike but last time I adjusted it the mark lined up with well centred on the ring and a click either side it was still engaged cleanly (IIRC). It's not the current model, and the clicks seem closer together than on my thumb shifter.

Answer (score 0):

The "fine tuning" that Chris H and Daniel R Hicks are mentioning is also called trim, and in addition to 'fine tuning' it allows you to counter-act the noise made by [cross chaining](https://www.google.com/search?q=cross+chaining&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=935&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=sIo8VZvEDIzZtQWFrIGwCw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ). Sheldon Brown talks about it [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/gear-theory.html#crossover) . Halfway down [this page](http://sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html), you will find info on Front Deraileurs. Perhaps more importantly on that page, search for "Indexing adjustment" to learn about how adjust the correlation between your shifter's number and where the mech actually is by using the barrel adjuster. (*Warning! Make sure you don't full unscrew any barrel adjusters, else your shifting will go to hell.)